# Networking Mac OS 9.2.2 with OS X and Windows

Tags: network, windows

I have heard about an abandonware program called Doubletalk by Connectix that is supposed to allow my old G4 running 9.2.2 talk to OSX Macs and Windows PCs by giving it the ability to do so by installing an SMB client.  I downloaded the program, no problem.  I installed the app as well as its update, and I can see some other computers in the Chooser window, but I have been unable to access any of them.  Every time I try, I get some kind of an error, whether it's "No response from the server, Please try again", or "guest access is not allowed" (when it is), or it seems to be accessing, but the shared file doesn't show up on the desktop.  I am stuck using a combination of legacy Macs, iMacs, and PCs on my network.  I don't have a choice.  I would sure appreciate any insight anyone can offer.

Comment: Does OS9 not include an SMB server? (For example, in an OS X computer, in System Preferences -> Sharing, you can enable File Sharing, which turns your computer into an SMB server. You can then use Finder -> Connect to Server to use SMB or AFP to connect to that computer.

Comment: No, OS 9 does not have native SMB.  It only has AFP.  You have to use a third party option.